gitlab backout changes from one env to another env
I have 2 feature branches A and B and three diff envs(test ,uat and prod).branch A made changes in file and commited and merged to test. Now after few days branch B made some changes to the same file and promoted to test and now both changes are in Test. Now suddenly branch A pushed his changes to UAT. but it took care of branch B changes also to the UAT . how to backout branch b changes from UAT aslo keeping branch A changes in UAT, we are using gitlab.
I tried git revert with it is reverting both branches changes

It's not entirely clear how this happened. If A was merged to Test and also to UAT, there is no explanation of how B ended up on UAT as well. Perhaps showing the graphical output would help, so something like: git log --graph branch_A branch_B Test UAT (Just substitute those 4 branches with their real names, and show enough of them so that we can see the HEADs of each branch and the common merge-base that they share.)
